# update jquery 1 to 3 for plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use this plugin (wm zoom : [GitHub](https://github.com/welisonmenezes/wm-zoom) ) and but there is a problem.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.wm-zoom-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

I changed or updated this code above:

```
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.wm-zoom-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

This code does not work, and with what code (function for js : [GitHub:JS](https://github.com/welisonmenezes/wm-zoom/blob/master/wm-zoom/jquery.wm-zoom-1.0.js)) can it be changed?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: console: http://s11.picofile.com/file/8393794292/rr.png

Comment: You will either need to manually change the source of that plugin to work with the latest version of jQuery, or find another up-to-date plugin which does what you need

Comment: *Generally* a change in the first number of a version number (in this case 1 to 3) means they are not compatible.

Comment: Other plugins have the same JQuery version 1 and 2,
but I didn't work manually change the source of that plugin to work with the latest version of jQuery. I want to use these plugins with the same version 3.0.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This plugin requires jquery version `1.9.1`

Comment: How can I do this manually in this plugin with jquery Version 3.0.0?

Comment: If you use higher jQuery version the plugin might work unexpectedly or might not work at all.